# Draw one Rectangle on Drag and Drop (canvas)

Tags: typescript, canvas, draw, drag

so i want to drag a rectangle out of the button in my canvas UI and place one new Rectangle on the Canvas, but everytime im trying to drag it out, it spawns alot of rectangles in a short period of time and then just stopps entirely. Where is the problem in my code?

update

```
    function update(): void {
    crc2.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
    crc2.putImageData(img, 0, 0);

    if (rectangleArray) {
        for (let i: number; i < rectangleArray.length; i++) {
            rectangleArray[i].draw();
        }
    }

    if (rectangleDragged == true) {
        currentRectangle.draw();
    }

    

}
```

handleMousedown

```
  function handleMousedown(_client: MouseEvent): void {

    let isLeftClicked = _client.which === 1;
    if (!isLeftClicked) return;

    if (_client.offsetX > xButton1 &&
        _client.offsetX < xButton1 + wButton1 &&
        _client.offsetY > yButton1 &&
        _client.offsetY < yButton1 + hButton1) {

        let rectangleDraw = new Draw(_client.offsetX, _client.offsetY);
        let rectangle = new Rectangle(0, rectangleDraw);
        currentRectangle = rectangle;            
        rectangleArray.push(rectangle);
        rectanglePresent = true;
        rectangleDragged = true;

        window.addEventListener("onclick", handleMousemoveRectangle);
        window.addEventListener("mouseup", handleMouseup);



        console.log(rectangleClick);

    }

   for (let rectangle of rectangleArray) {

        if (
            rectanglePresent == true &&
            _client.offsetX > rectangle.position.x - rectangle.w / 2 &&
            _client.offsetX < rectangle.position.x + rectangle.w / 2 &&
            _client.offsetY > rectangle.position.y - rectangle.h / 2 &&
            _client.offsetY < rectangle.position.y + rectangle.h / 2) {

            window.addEventListener("mousemove", handleMousemoveRectangle);
            currentRectangle = rectangle;
            rectangleDragged = true;
        }
    }
}
```

handleMouseup

```
    function handleMouseup(_client: MouseEvent): void {

    if (dragged) {
        setTimeout(() => {
            dragged = false;
        },         1000);

    }

    for (let rectangle of rectangleArray) {
        currentRectangle = rectangle;
        if (rectanglePresent == true &&
            currentRectangle.position.y > 600
        ) {
            let index: number = rectangleArray.indexOf(currentRectangle);
            rectangleArray.splice(index, 1);
        }
        
    }

    window.removeEventListener("mousemove", handleMousemoveRectangle);
    window.removeEventListener("mouseup", handleMouseup);

}
```

handleMousemoveRectangle

```
   export function handleMousemoveRectangle(_client: MouseEvent): void {
    currentRectangle.position.x = _client.offsetX;
    currentRectangle.position.y = _client.offsetY;
    currentRectangle.draw();
    rectangleDragged = true;
    dragged = true;
    console.log();      
}
```

Comment: From your description of the problem, I _suspect_ that your context is not being cleared each time you draw a rectangle. Is there any way you could create a running sandbox with [codepen](https://codepen.io/) or a similar service?

Comment: Uhm so i copied my code to codepen, but i cant add another js file. Because i use a Draw JS and a Rectangle JS to "Draw" the rectangle on click, i hope you know what i mean by that, and maybe there is a way to get multiple js files but im rly not sure how. but here is the link https://codepen.io/eugib/pen/mdVZzrP          so its about the first button with the rectangle